# Using nslookup on every line and inserting into a specific column

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have a text file with 10 lines in it containing the following:

```
Linux Server myhostname on mount point /var is XX% full
```

I would like to do an nslookup on each line for myhostname, pull out the IP address of the server and insert it after full on each line... Any suggestions on how to acoomplish?

Comment: Why do you want to use `nslookup`? It's deprecated. Would the command `host` be acceptable?

Answer (score 2):

`nslookup` is deprecated and I cannot even install it on my system, but the command `host` can help you.

Use this:

```
while read -r line 
do 
    ip=$(host $(echo $line | cut -f 3 -d ' ') | head -n 1 | cut -f 4 -d ' ')
    echo $line $ip >> newhosts 
done < hosts
```

After I've run this, my `newhosts` looks like this:

```
Linux Server google.se on mount point /var is XX% full 216.58.209.99
Linux Server stackoverflow.com on mount point /var is XX% full 151.101.1.69
Linux Server yahoo.se on mount point /var is XX% full 74.6.136.150
Linux Server flashback.org on mount point /var is XX% full 212.85.75.180
```

After this, you could just invoke `mv newhosts hosts`

Comment: Guybrush Threepwood? Really?? :D

Comment: Thanks klutt, I will give that a try!

Comment: The command worked, but I got servername.fqdn.org is an alias for servername.xxx.xxx.

Comment: @MichaelW. Please give an example of a server where it does that.

Comment: @klutt output from my text file is as follows,Linux Server pp1dev on mount point / is 92% full.... I ran you're command against the input text file and now it says Linux Server pp1dev on mount point / is 92% full pp1dev.infinite-blue.com is an alias for pp1dev.mf.infinite

Comment: @MichaelW. I meant, do you have a *public* server I can try this against. It's hard to find a solution if I cannot reproduce the problem.

Comment: Try this line: `ip=$(host $(echo $line | cut -f 3 -d ' ') | grep "has address" | head -n 1 | cut -f 4 -d ' ')`

Comment: @klutt sorry I do not have a public example.... so now I returned the IP address but I want to get rid of the fqdn now

Comment: @MichaelW. I think it's a bit to complex to solve here in comments. I suggest you start a new question.